# Optimising subdiagonal shift matrix generation time

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I want a square matrix $A$ such that $$A_{i,i-1} = 1 \ \forall i\\ A_{i,j} = 0 \text{ for } \ j \ne i-1$$

I have tried

```
tminus[n_] := Table[If[i == j + 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

This is much better than

```
tminus[n_] := Module[{m = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], i, j}, 
                     For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
                         For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
                             If[i == j + 1, m[[i, j]] = 1, m[[i, j]] = 0]
                            ];
                        ];
                     Return[m];
                    ]
```

However, I wanted to know a better and optimised version so that I can create matrices of order 10000 and higher.

Comment: try not to use For loops in Mathematica. There are faster, efficient functional ways of implementing stuff without using loops. For loops are error-prone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your matrix is large and has very few nonzero elements it is much more efficient to create and store it as a `SparseArray`. In addition many matrix operations are optimized to work faster with SparseArrays.

In order to efficiently generate sparse subdiagonal matrix you can use following function:

```
tminus7[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n-1, SparseArray], -1]
```

Both `DiagonalMatrix` and `ConstantArray` can output SparseArrays,
but you have to explicitly specify `SparseArray` option, otherwise a large non-sparse array will be generated at intermediate step and the performance will be much lower (as shown by `tminus2` function in kglr's answer).

Let's compare this method with the fastest function from kglr's answer (`tminus1`):

```
tminus1[n_] := ArrayPad[IdentityMatrix[n - 1, SparseArray], {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]

n=10000;
t1=First[RepeatedTiming[r1=tminus1[n];]];
t7=First[RepeatedTiming[r7=tminus7[n];]];
Equal[r1,r7]
```

> True

```
{t1,t7}
```

> {0.000072, 0.000025}

Thus, for large matrices this function is about 3 times faster than the fastest function (`tminus1`) from the top answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
ClearAll[tminus1, tminus2, tminus3, tminus4, tminus5]
tminus1[n_] := ArrayPad[IdentityMatrix[n - 1, SparseArray], {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
tminus2[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n-1], -1]
tminus3[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j == (i - 1) -> 1, {n, n}]
tminus4[n_] := IdentityMatrix[n+1, SparseArray][[;;-2, 2;;]]
tminus5[n_] := Drop[IdentityMatrix[n+1, SparseArray], {-1}, {1}]

tminus1[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Timings:** Including `tminus0` (from OP) , `tminus6` (from Roman's answer) and `tminus7` (from Shadowray's answer):

```
tminus0[n_] := Table[If[i == j + 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] 
tminus6[n_] := SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, {n, n}] 
tminus7[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n-1, SparseArray], -1] 

funcs ={"tminus1 - arraypad", "tminus3 - sparsearray", "tminus4 - part", 
   "tminus5 - drop","tminus6 - sparsearray-band", "tminus7 - diagonalmatrix-sparseArray"};
```

Version/OS:

```
$Version (on Wolfram Cloud)
```

> 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

```
n = 100;
t0 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r0 = tminus0[n];]];
t1 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r1 = tminus1[n];]];
t2 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r2 = tminus2[n];]];
t3 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r3 = tminus3[n];]];
t4 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r4 = tminus4[n];]];
t5 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r5 = tminus5[n];]];
t6 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r6 = tminus6[n];]];
t7 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r7 = tminus7[n];]];
Equal[r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7]
```

> True

```
timings = {t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7};
Column[{"n = 100",
  Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{funcs, timings}], Last], 
   {"function", "timing"}], Dividers -> All, Alignment -> "."]}]
```

[image]

[image]

I exclude `tminus0`  and `tminus2` (due limited cloud credit) for `n = 10000` and for `n = 100000`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Astonishing timings! Thanks, this comparison is very useful.

Comment: @kglr, could you add a column to your tables to show specifically which functions `tminusX` go with which times and function cores? I keep scrolling up and down to mentally correlate. Super useful data, thanks!

Comment: Also, which version of Mathematica used.

Comment: @MikeY, please see the update.

Comment: Worth adding Shadowray's fully `SparseArray` implementation of `tminus2` to your table

Comment: @b3m2a1, added  Shadowray's  `tminus7`.

Answer (score 11):

```
tminus[n_Integer /; n >= 2] := SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, {n, n}]
```